# tinymce angular image picker syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, tinymce, angular-directive

I have a ionic app which uses angular and I want to drop in an image picker into the tinymce editor which I introduced on the page.

In the tinymce [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/), as far as I can gather, it says to use an angular directive in the html file (I also used the `ngModel` from [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/angular/#usingthengmodeldirective)):

```
 <h1>TinyMCE 5 Angular Demo</h1>
 <editor
   [(ngModel)]="dataModel"
   [init]="{
     height: 500,
     menubar: false,
     plugins: [
       'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
       'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
       'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
     ],
     toolbar:
       'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | \
       alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
       bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help'
   }"
 ></editor>
```

It's all working ok, but now I want to add an image picker, but the [docs for that](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#file_picker_callback) imply to use js in the ts file, like so:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
    // Provide file and text for the link dialog
    if (meta.filetype == 'file') {
      callback('mypage.html', {text: 'My text'});
    }

    // Provide image and alt text for the image dialog
    if (meta.filetype == 'image') {
      callback('myimage.jpg', {alt: 'My alt text'});
    }

    // Provide alternative source and posted for the media dialog
    if (meta.filetype == 'media') {
      callback('movie.mp4', {source2: 'alt.ogg', poster: 'image.jpg'});
    }
  }
});
```

I am now a bit stuck as I need to call `file_picker_callback` from the directive in the html and I can't seem to find out how.

Alternatively, I thought I could reference the `ngModel` from the js/ts file instead of the html file, but again I am a bit stuck as I am not sure what to look up.

I have started to read the angular docs to get a grasp of what is going on (and what to do) but a bit of steering in the right direction wouldn't go amiss.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually quite simple, just use the `this` keyword in the html file:

```
file_picker_callback: this.filePickerCallback
```

Then create the function `filePickerCallback` in the typescript file.